# How to get the contributors on OpenStreetMap

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql

I have put my osm file in base thanks to osm2pgsql and I am looking for a way to get the contributor list. I have searched in my database and haven't found so much... and the osm wiki about the osm2pgsql schema does not contain a lot of details...

Is it possible?

Comment: not sure if this useful - its online and finds users contributions http://hdyc.neis-one.org/

Comment: Not useful for what I need, but it's an interesting online feature. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you have used the `-x` switch then the database that osm2pgsql creates won't include any contributor information. The main use for those databases is rendering which doesn't normally need to know who created an object, and including that information makes the database much larger, so it is normally left out.

That information is in the planet file though - in the `user` and `uid` attributes on each object. You may find you are better off writing some custom software to read planet and build a database of that information.

Comment: I was thinking about customizing the osm2pgsql to add contributors... Anyway thank you for your answer.